# Can implement a method when click the "dismiss" button after the alarm sounded in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to implement a method when the "dismiss" button clicked, but in the alarm class I can't find any event for it.Are there sb. do this before? Can sb. give me a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. Alarms / schedules actions are a system level feature, when an alarm fires it does not cause any of your application code to execute so there is no way to handle events relating to the alarm.